# Not able to change date format using SQL date function FORMAT(DateColumn,''yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, datetime

I am using below SQL query and want to change date format from marketing cloud Date format i.e. "Monday, May 13, 2019 12:00 AM" to "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"

I have Used SQL Query , but resultant Column (purchaseDate) printing same date-time i.e. Monday, May 13, 2019 12:00 AM , any suggestion to print date in this format ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

both ORDERDATE and purchaseDate fields are Date filed in Marketing Cloud DEs

```sql
select 
OrderNumber, 
Customermail, 
FORMAT(ORDERDATE,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ') as purchaseDate 
where customerEmail is not null
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the data type of `OrderDate` in the source Data Extension.  Also please indicate the data type of of `PurchaseDate` in the target Data Extension.  All `Date` data types in SFMC are SQL Server [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) format, so if you want it in some other format, you'll need to make the target column _Text_.

Comment: Also, why do you need it in that specific format in a query?  Is it being exported?

Comment: Thanks Adam , yes we are going to export Source DE to other system which required specific date format.  ….also I had already mentioned data type of both the date fields  in my original question ( please check statement above SQL query) :)

Answer (score 1):

The target Data Extension column for `purchaseDate` needs to be Text (20).

Then the format function will work as you intended.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/jwGtomcL